# Passing dynamic value to partitioner code in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I wrote the below code to filter out the lines which are not matching to 141,but I want this 141 to be dynamic and want to pass a value from the command line while executing this map reduce program.
I am not sure how to pass the arguments from main function to the partitioner class.

```
public class CharecterCountPartitioner extends Partitioner <Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int numReduceTasks) {

      //int line_length=Integer.parseInt();
      if(value.get() == 141) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return 1 % numReduceTasks;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Partitioner` can implement the [interface `Configurable`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configurable.html), which gives you callbacks when the configuration was injected via reflection.

Just implement the interface and on `setConf(Configuration conf)` you can fetch your configuration value from the commandline and use it as a field in your class.

```
public class CharecterCountPartitioner extends Partitioner <Text, IntWritable> implements Configurable {

    int lineLength;    

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int numReduceTasks) { // do stuff }

   @Override
   public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
       lineLength = conf.getInt("whatever");
   }

   @Override
   public Configuration getConf() {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the sample on how to implement it?

Comment: Have a view at this [link](https://cornercases.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/an-example-configurable-partitioner/)